# How do I remove these two commands my terminal is running upon start-up?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed something from my old Windows sub-system for Linux environment in my Ububtu environment on accident and I do not know what it is. Now when I open the Ubuntu terminal it runs two commands that were necessary for the wsl and I get this output at the top of the terminal =>
`cmd.exe: command not found`
`wslpath: command not found`

I want to find out what I have installed and remove it.

Comment: They're probably in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, remove those lines.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.